# Taylor Window Algorithm

Tags: window-functions

I am trying to find out the algorithm for taylor window function but i have looked everywhere and i dont see any proper algorithm.
I read it is similar to Kaiser Window but thats all I know.

Can someone help me find the algorithm?

Comment: The Taylor window taper function approximates the Dolph-Chebyshev window’s
constant sidelobe level for a parameterized number of near-in sidelobes, but then allows a taper beyond. This makes it realizable, and in fact popular in some signal processing circles, especially radar signal processing. P. 132: https://www.osti.gov/servlets/purl/1365510  (https://se.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/taylorwin.html Taylor windows are similar to Chebyshev windows. A Chebyshev window has the narrowest possible mainlobe for a specified sidelobe level, but a Taylor window allows you to make tradeoffs ...)

Comment: Seems to me @JuhaP that this could be placed in an answer.  Then you get some rep for it.

Comment: @JuhaP, I agree it can be an answer, if you include the actual formula from the paper (or maybe a screenshot would do)

Comment: See section 7 of https://digital.library.unt.edu/ark:/67531/metadc893840/m2/1/high_res_d/932884.pdf

Answer (score 3):

By [Catalog of Window Taper Functions for Sidelobe Control](https://www.osti.gov/servlets/purl/1365510), (Armin W. Doerry, Sandia National Laboratories, p.132) The Taylor window taper function approximates the [Dolph-Chebyshev](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Window_function#Dolph%E2%80%93Chebyshev_window) window’s
constant sidelobe level for a parameterized number of near-in sidelobes, but then allows a taper beyond. This makes it realizable, and in fact popular in some signal processing circles, especially radar signal processing.

The window function itself, scaled for unit DC gain, is calculated as

$$ w(t) = \left( 1 + 2 \sum_{m=1}^{\bar{n}-1} F_m \cos(2\pi mt) \right)\operatorname{rect}(t)$$

Where $F_m$ = coefficients (equation to solve coefficients can be found from source documentation) and $\bar{n}$ = the distance from the mainlobe for which sidelobes are constant.

Window Utilities (Matlab) package by Joe Henning includes [taylwin.m](https://se.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/46092-window-utilities?s_tid=srchtitle).

Additional resources:

@GrapefruitIsAwesome's [link](https://digital.library.unt.edu/ark:/67531/metadc893840/m2/1/high_res_d/932884.pdf) in comments section.

Mathwork's function reference for [taylorwin.m](https://se.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/taylorwin.html).